# Using multiple function for COUNTIFS in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, count, google-sheets-formula

```
=COUNTIFS((Tab1!C2:Tab1!C250),"*sam*") & ((Tab1!B2:Tab1!B250), ">1-Nov-2020")
```

In the above formula, I'm trying to get the count of 'person names whose name is `sam` and the value which is past `1-Nov-2020`.
While trying to fetch the count using the above formula, it is showing `Formula parse error`.

Please analyze and tell where might I went wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to correct your syntax to:

```
=COUNTIFS('Tab1'!C2:C9,"sam", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">1-Nov-2020")
```

[image]

Please read [more on how the COUNTIFS function work](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256550).

---

**EDIT** *(following OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64724115/using-multiple-function-for-countifs-in-google-sheets/64724389?noredirect=1#comment114442641_64724389))*

The correct syntax would be
`COUNTIFS(criteria_range1, criterion1, [criteria_range2, …], [criterion2, …])` meaning:

```
=COUNTIFS('Tab1'!C2:C9,"sam", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">1-Nov-2020", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">=1-11-2020")
```

**BUT**

Since you refer to dates `1-Nov-2020` is the same as `1-11-2020`.
So you only need

```
=COUNTIFS('Tab1'!C2:C9,"sam", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">=1-11-2020")
```

**OR**

```
=COUNTIFS('Tab1'!C2:C9,"sam", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">=1-Nov-2020")
```

Comment: That's cool. If I want to add one more condition with the date that is like, 
  " =COUNTIFS('Tab1'!C2:C9,"sam", 'Tab1'!B2:B9,">1-Nov-2020" or ">=1-11-2020") "      will it work? Or what is the correct syntax to add OR condition here?

Comment: You are almost there. Please see my updated answer. If still in need please let us know.